# viewWillTransition(to:with:) within UIViewControllerRepresentable: new view bounds size still not available in alongsideTransition

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, viewwilltransitiontosize

I am migrating an UIKit project to SwiftUI but will keep one UIKit ViewController, which now will be wrapped using an `UIViewControllerRepresentable` View.

Everything seems to be working fine, except for the animation during the change of device orientation.

The problem seems to be the fact that - other than in a pure UIKit environment - the new `view.bounds.size` is still not available within the `alongsideTransition:` block in `viewWillTransition(to:with:)`. The new size is available for the first time in the `completion:` block.

This can be seen in the following demo project:

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        UIKitView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

**UIKitView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct UIKitView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: UIKitView
        init(_ parent: UIKitView) { self.parent = parent }
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController { ViewController() }

    func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: ViewController, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator { Coordinator(self) }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var labelTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        updateConstraints()
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
        label.text = "This is a sample text"
        label.textColor = .yellow
        label.backgroundColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .center
        
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(label)
        
        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 300.0)
        let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200.0)
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topConstraint, centerXConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
        
        self.labelTopConstraint = topConstraint
    }
    
    func updateConstraints() {
        // simple illustration, calculation in actual project much more complex
        labelTopConstraint.constant = view.bounds.size.height / 2.0
        view.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    override func viewWillTransition(
        to size: CGSize,
        with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator
    ) {
        print("view.bounds.size at Start: \(self.view.bounds.size)")
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        
        coordinator.animate(
            alongsideTransition: { [weak self] _ in
                print("view.bounds.size during Animation: \(self?.view.bounds.size ?? .zero)")
                self?.updateConstraints()
            },
            completion: { [weak self] _ in
                print("view.bounds.size during Completion: \(self?.view.bounds.size ?? .zero)")
                
                // the following is to demo where the label should have been placed during the transition
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
                    self?.updateConstraints()
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Running the app and rotating the Simulator generates the following console output:

```
view.bounds.size at Start: (428.0, 926.0)
view.bounds.size during Animation: (428.0, 926.0)  // still not updated!
view.bounds.size during Completion: (926.0, 428.0)
```

In comparison, when rotating the Simulator running exactly the same ViewController in a pure UIKit application, the console output is:

```
view.bounds.size at Start: (428.0, 926.0)
view.bounds.size during Animation: (926.0, 428.0)  // new size is already available here!
view.bounds.size during Completion: (926.0, 428.0)
```

As a workaround I tried calling `updateConstraints()` from `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, but it is called too late (after the `alongsideTransition:` animation block), which gets noticeable in a more complex setup.

I am running the code in `Xcode 13.4.1` and `iOS 15.5`. The behaviour is identical in  `Xcode 14` / `iOS 16` beta 2.

Is there a way to get the new view size to be available already in the `alongsideTransition:` animation block?

Comment: IMO that is implementation specific and non-proved expectation - instead `to size` of `viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize` should be used as it is the one explicitly stated new size and updated correctly.

Comment: Thanks, @Asperi. Unfortunately in my specific case ```size``` is not what I really need as it is the container size (screen size), which is different from my ViewController's size as it is within a navigation controller.